# Maximum principle or comparison principle

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, maximum-principle, parabolic-pde

the equation
$\varphi_t + D_p H(x, Du ^\varepsilon)\cdot D \varphi = \varepsilon\Delta \varphi$ is a linear parabolic equation. Thus, by the comparison principle for parabolic equations, we have for all $(x,t)\in \mathbb{R}^n\times[0,\infty)$,
$\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\varphi (x,0) \leq \varphi (x,t) \leq \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n}\varphi (x,0)$. My question is what the comparison principle is used here, and does it use some assumption?
I know something like this about heat equation. Please teach me.

Comment: The statement is not true even for heat equation (some growth conditions on $\varphi$ is needed).

Comment: That’s right. Thanks.